# Error while creating DTD file

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to create a DTD file but I unfortunately I am getting an error, please advice. 
Here is my code

```
<!ELEMENT SUB_CONDITION EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST SUB_CONDITION relation (=|<>|>|<|>=|<=|=Mask|<>Mask) #REQUIRED>
```

the error is saying:
"The name token is required in the enumerated type list for the "relation" attribute declaration."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<`, `=`, and `>` characters (#x003C, #x003D, #x003E) are not allowed in attribute values declared as enumerated.

In an attribute declared to have [enumerated values](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Enumeration), the values must match `Nmtoken` (one or more `NameChar`s). That excludes several characters, including `<`, `=`, and `>`, which are not part of [the definition of `NameChar`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar).

`<` is especially troublesome (it is the start-of-tag delimiter in XML markup) and is [not allowed in any attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#CleanAttrVals).

Comment: Thank you mzjn for your response, so what do you suggest I do in this case, I need to place these characters in the enumerated values.

Comment: If you must have enumerated values, you could rename them using allowed characters. Something like this perhaps: `(eq|neq|gt|lt|gtoreq|ltoreq|eqMask|neqMask)`.